# Dynamic relationship class loading with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a library via which I dynamically load classes.  It's exposed as

```
mylib.registry.<className>
```

registry is an instance of a class that contains a dictionary of class name (strings) to module names, and a **getattr** call that dynamically loads a class if it is requested.  A user can thus refer to any class without having to deal with the module locations (there is a global namespace for class names, but not module names).

For example, the entries:

```
{'X', 'mylib.sublib.x',
 'Y', 'mylib.sublib.y'}
```

could then be used like:

```
import mylib

x = mylib.registry.X()
y = mylib.registry.Y()
```

That's the background. On top of this, these objects are sqlalchemy ORM classes which have relationships to one another.  Let's assume here that X has a one-to-many with Y.

Assume thus this definition.

```
class X(Base):
    y_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('y.id'))
    y = relationship('Y')

class Y(Base):
    xs = relationship('X')
```

These are in separate files, and each imports the top-level registry.

So here's the issue -- how do I actually get this to resolve without loading every class up front?

The example above doesn't work, because if I import only X via the registry, then Y isn't in sqlalchemy class registry, and thus the relatiobship breaks.

If I import the registry itself and then refer to the classes directly, then the modules don't load because of interdependencies.

I tried using a lambda to defer loading, but this too fails with an error about a missing 'strategy'.

What approaches have others used here?   If I'm missing something obvious, let me know.  It's been a long day.

Thanks.

Comment: All right -- I think I have this down to a more basic problem.

It seems that if one uses a callable when defining a relationship, the other side cannot be a callable.  Unfortunately, the class one is loading first has to be the one without the callable.

This is stupid.  It cannot be this hard to have a bidirectional field that doesn't require loading both classes upfront.  Doing lambda: class seemed to be the right approach, but if you do it on both sides (and use back_populates) an attribute error is thrown -- 'RelationshipProperty' object has no attribute 'strategy'.  Irritating.

Answer (score 1):

You should never use relationships on two sides that don't know about each other. Normally, this is avoided by using `backref` but in your case this creates problems, because you want each side to be aware of its relationship by itself. The trick here is the `back_populates` keyword, offered by [`relationship`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship):

```
y = relationship("Y", back_populates="xs")
```

and

```
xs = relationship("X", back_populates="y")
```

Applying these will make them aware of each other. However, it will not solve your importing problem. Normally, you could now just `from x import X` on the `Y` side. But the other way around won't work because it will create a circular import.

The trick is simple: Put the import *after* the class you want to import. Because the strings in `relationship` are evaluated lazily, you can import the class *after* the relationship was defined. So for `X` do this:

```
class X(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'x'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    y_id = Column(ForeignKey('y.id'))
    y = relationship("Y", back_populates="xs")

from y import Y
```

And the other way around for the `Y` as well (this is not required, but creates more symmetry). I'd also put a comment there to explain this to avoid someone putting it to the top, breaking the program.

Comment: I don't agree.  

This introduces unnecessary coupling to the object model.  I should be able to, say, own a list of books without the books necessarily knowing themselves who they're owned by.

Second, operationally, it introduces the risk that one side of the operation would return a small set of items, but the other side a massive set, with little real-world use cases or at least reliance on the handling of a huge dataset by the implementation.  For example, user.UTCsPurchased, over the life of a user, may be a large but not unwieldy set.  utc.boughtBy might be billions of rows.

Comment: That said, this comment of mine is tangential to the original question.  I ended up using backref, and dynamic loading via a single module.  It works fine without lots of imports scattered throughout the code.

Comment: Because of the mentioned problem, you have lazy loading. This effectively means: If you don't access it, it won't be fetched and if you access it you obviously need it and want it to be loaded. A backref does not increase the size of the data nor usage of memory (except for a few references), because the data is already present. I don't say that you must use the backref, but if you use bidirectional relationships as in your case, than inform them about each other. There is almost no overhead for it but it keeps things consistent.

Comment: Doing a flask app now and circular relationships in SQLAlchemy are a real disaster. Wish this answer could be upvoted more